# reading a file into stream in windows store App without using async/await

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-store-apps, async-await

I want to read a file from the assets into a stream, I currently use it as the following:

```
public async void LoadWidthOfUnicodesData()
{

    string dataFile = @"Assets\QuranData\Data_Font1.xml";
    StorageFolder InstallationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    StorageFile file = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync(dataFile);
    Stream readStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();            
    DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<UniCodeWidth>));
    WidthOfUnicodes = (List<UniCodeWidth>)ser.ReadObject(readStream);
    for (int i = 0; i < WidthOfUnicodes.Count; i++)
    {
        WidthOfUnicodesDict.Add(WidthOfUnicodes[i].UniCode, WidthOfUnicodes[i].Width);
    }
}
```

The only problem with that, is that part is in my viewmodel, and as it's a non-blocking operation, when the VM initializes with the View as its DataContext, the constructor does what it's supposed to do to fill the view but I always get an exception at using the `WidthOfUnicodesDict` because it's not yet filled with the data.

What I want to do, is either make the reading to stream a synchronous method (without using async/await) which so far I don't know how to do it on windows store. or somehow make the VM constructor waits till this operation finishes and notifies it's done.

Comment: Have a look at [Stephen Cleary's article about `async` and constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Comment: If it's reading from a file, it's a blocking operation.

Answer (score -1):

You can fetch a file without async/await semantics like this:

```
var file = Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(Folder)
               .GetAwaiter()
               .GetResult();
```

I don't know how to get a stream, but you can get an `IBuffer` or read it as text, using [`FileIO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.aspx):

```
string content = FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
IList lines = FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
IBuffer buffer = FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I've done this before and it doesn't cause any deadlocks.

Comment: But it will block the UI thread, which is why you should never do this.

Comment: @svick *if* it is run on the UI thread, yes. But isn't that what the OP was looking for? To run it synchronously?

Comment: When a question asks “How to do X?”, sometimes the correct answer is “Don't do X, do Y instead, this is how.”

Comment: Why not simply `var file = <something async>.Result`

Comment: @dcastro, looks like you are going through hoops and loops trying to avoid the disaster you're running into. Like @I3arnon said, `X.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` when applied to `Task` is the same as `X.Result`.

Comment: @PauloMorgado It seems both you and @I3arnon are under the false assumption that methods like `GetFileAsync` return a `Task<T>`. They don't, they return an `IAsyncOperation<T>`, which does not have a `Result` property. I'm not going through hoops, I'm simply retrieving the result of the operation. And what disaster am I running into?

Comment: @dcastro, than my question would be: why are you calling `X.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `X.GetResults() `?

Comment: @PauloMorgado I've tried it before, and it either lead to a deadlock or an exception. Can't remember, that was a while ago. I think it threw an exception, because it tried to retrieve the result of the operation immediately, but the results weren't available yet.